# Работа с двумя SerialPort C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, serial

Задача заключается в следующем. Необходимо работать с двумя COM портами одновременно. Настройки портов разные как и имя порта. Методы для работы (чтение - запись) так же могут быть разными. Не понимаю архитектурно как это сделать. Создавать два почти идентичных класса для работы с портом, попахивает дублированием. Сейчас делаю так, но то же не понимаю, как можно в одном классе аккумулировать работу с двумя последовательными портами и инициализировать два разных порта с разными настройками.
Класс настроек:

```
 public class FirstPort
{
    public string PortName { get; set; } = "COM1";
    public int BaudRate { get; set; } = 38400;
    public int DataBits { get; set; } = 8;
    public StopBits StopBits { get; set; } = StopBits.One;
    public Parity Parity {get;set;} = Parity.None;
}

public class SecondPort
{
    public string PortName { get; set; } = "COM2";
    public int BaudRate { get; set; } = 19200;
    public int DataBits { get; set; } = 8;
    public StopBits StopBits { get; set; } = StopBits.One;
    public Parity Parity { get; set; } = Parity.None;
}
```

Основной класс:

```
public class CustomSerialPort : SerialPort
{
    public event DataRecievedEventHandler DataChanged;

    public delegate void DataRecievedEventHandler(object sender, string package);

    private object locker = new object();

    public CustomSerialPort(что - то port)
        : base()
    {
        base.PortName = port.PortName;
        base.BaudRate = port.BaudRate;
        base.DataBits = port.DataBits;
        base.StopBits = port.StopBits;
        base.Parity = port.StopBits;
        base.DataReceived += CustomSerialPortDataReceived; ;
    }

    public void Open(string portName)
    {
        if (base.IsOpen)
        {
            base.Close();
        }
        base.PortName = portName;
        base.Open();
    }

    private void CustomSerialPortDataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        var port = (SerialPort)sender;

        lock (locker)
        {
            try
            {
                DataChanged?.Invoke(sender, port.ReadExisting());
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(exception);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var port = new CustomSerialPort();
        port.Open("COM1");

         port.DataChanged += Port_DataChanged;

        Console.WriteLine(port.ReadExisting());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static void Port_DataChanged(object sender, string package)
    {
       Console.Write(package.Replace("\r", "\n"));
    }
```

Или перегрузить конструктор и в них передавать экземпляры  FirstPort, SecondPort?

Comment: Нет никакого смысла делать два одинаковых класса `FirstPort, SecondPort`. Нужно делать два разных экземпляра c разными значениями свойств одного и того же класса SerialPort.

Comment: Я вот и не понимаю как это сделать... `public CustomSerialPort(FirstPort port)
            : base()` `public CustomSerialPort(SecondPort port)
            : base()`' тип такого что-то?

Answer (score 1):

Здесь вообще не нужны классы FirstPort и SecondPort. Создайте в вашем классе CustomSerialPort конструктор с параметрами:

```
public CustomSerialPort(string port, int baud, int dataBits,  StopBits stopBits, Parity parity)
    {
        PortName = port;
        BaudRate = baud;
        DataBits = dataBits;
        StopBits = stopBits;
        Parity = parity;
        DataReceived += CustomSerialPortDataReceived;
    }
```

А при использовании создайте два экземпляра с разными параметрами:

```
CustomSerialPort port1 = new CustomSerialPort("COM1", 38400, 8, StopBits.None, Parity.None);
CustomSerialPort port2 = new CustomSerialPort("COM2", 19200, 8, StopBits.None, Parity.None);
```

И используйте их как вам угодно. Если например, для них будет разная логика обработки в DataReceived, то в классе добавить второе такое событие, сделать их public static, убрать из конструктора DataReceived и назначать непосредственно объектам при использовании следующим образом:

```
port1.DataReceived += CustomSerialPort.CustomSerialPortDataReceived1;
port2.DataReceived += CustomSerialPort.CustomSerialPortDataReceived2;
```